# Build error for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' in Android while binding?

Tags: java, android-viewbinding, kapt, invocationtargetexception, android-viewbinder

While building the code I got an error as follows. My functionality is to implement Rest API calls from the app to implement various service requests.

```
 E  USNET: appName: appname
 2023-02-13 04:22:51.762  6407-10658 pageboostd pid-6407                             
 E  aal_prefetch_file alp wrong file 
 name:/data/app/~~KJpgJDsTQ8Oi9eoFEOIhmA==/appname- 
 Nm5W59HYVYOE_v6Ua3SYRQ==/oat/arm64/base.art
 2023-02-13 04:22:52.194  5223-5255  WindowManager           pid-5223                             
 E  win=Window{6a35d31 u0 Splash Screen appnameEXITING} destroySurfaces: 
 appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true 
 win.mViewVisibility=8 
 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5860 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5841 
 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5972 
 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:242 
 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6225
 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer 
 $$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onAnimationFinished:2
 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$ 
 SurfaceAnimator:113 
 2023-02-13 04:23:03.151  5223-5843  WindowManager pid-5223                             
 E  win=Window{dc92b4c u0 appname /appname.SplashScreenActivity} 
 destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false 
 win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 
 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5860 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5841 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5905 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6547 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 
 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130 
 2023-02-13 04:23:40.724  5223-7672  WindowManager           pid-5223                             
 E  win=Window{dc92b4c u0 appname /appname .SplashScreenActivity} 
 destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false 
 win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 
 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5860 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5841 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5905 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6547 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:254 
 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596 
 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:130
```

Execution failed for task
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
Found 3 data binding error(s)

Please help me to correct the error as soon as possible

Thank you!

Comment: Please help regarding the error as I am a newbie in kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the build error is due to the view binding mechanism failure. I commented some suspicious code and finally rebuilt the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this link for showing icons https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/how-to-use-a-recycler-view-to-show-images-from-storage